# Creating HTML file via heredoc in Perl fails with Bareword error

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure out how to create a simple HTML file using a heredoc in Perl but I keep getting

```
Bareword found where operator expected at pscratch.pl line 12, near "<title>Test"
    (Missing operator before Test?)
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at pscratch.pl line 13.
syntax error at pscratch.pl line 11, near "head>"
Execution of pscratch.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I can't figure out what the issue is. This is the script in its entirety:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh;
my $file = "/home/msadmin1/bin/testing/html.test";

open($fh, '>', $file) or die "Cannot open $file: \n $!";

print $fh << "EOF";
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>This is a test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
EOF

close($fh);
```

I've tried using both single and double quotes around `EOF`. I've also tried escaping all of the `<>` tags which didn't help.

What should I be doing to prevent this error?

**EDIT**

I know there are modules out there that will simplify this, but I'd like to know what the problem is with this before I simplify the task with a module.

**EDIT 2**

The error seems to indicate that Perl is looking at the text within the heredoc as a substitution due to the `/` in the closing tags. If I escape them part of the error goes away regarding `space between pattern and following word` but the rest of the error remains.

Comment: Remove space after `<<`.

Comment: Thanks! Please make that the answer so I can select it.

Comment: With the space, it is a shift operation http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Shift-Operators so Perl is interpreting your HTML as Perl code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space infront of the `<< "EOF";` as it is not interacting nicely with the filehandle print.

Here are various working/non-working variants:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $foo = << "EOF";
OK: with space into a variable
EOF

print $foo;

print <<"EOF";
OK: without space into a regular print
EOF

print << "EOF";
OK: with space into a regular print
EOF

open my $fh, ">foo" or die "Unable to open foo : $!";
print $fh <<"EOF";
OK: without space into a filehandle print
EOF

# Show file output
close $fh;
print `cat foo`;

# This croaks
eval ' 
print $fh << "EOF";
with space into a filehandle print
EOF
';
if ($@) {
    print "FAIL: with space into a filehandle print\n"
}

# Throws a bitshift warning:
print "FAIL: space and filehandle means bitshift!\n";
print $fh << "EOF";
print "\n";
```

**Output**

```
OK: with space into a variable
OK: without space into a regular print
OK: with space into a regular print
OK: without space into a filehandle print
FAIL: with space into a filehandle print
FAIL: space and filehandle means bitshift!
Argument "EOF" isn't numeric in left bitshift (<<) at foo.pl line 42.
152549948
```